# Обмен данными между множеством ПК с помощью единственного сайта на c#

Tags: c#

Подскажите как можно реализовать обмен данными между множеством ПК с помощью одного сайта на c#.
**Именно сайт на хостинге, а не целый сервер.**
Все клиенты будут работать через standalone-приложение.

P.S. интересуют двухсторонние запросы

Comment: Очень просто - один клиент (или несколько) на сайт может чтото отсылать, а другой (или другие) что то с сайта загружать.

Comment: @tym32167 , а где хранить данные в промежутке, после того как, первый клиент отправил их и перед тем, как другой клиент их примет ?

Comment: Либо в памяти, либо в базе данных, либо в файлах - это уже зависит от ваших требований и возможностей

Comment: @relevant зависит от вида данных

Comment: @eXCore если просто текст

Comment: @relevant после передачи в потоке сохраняете текст в виде файла например, ну а после сохранения ждёте запроса. Тут важно, чтобы потоки не стучались к данным другого потока, и всё будет ок.

Comment: Любую БД берите и не парьтесь. на хостингах повсеместно стоит mysql и обычно есть postgesql

Comment: Для двустороннего общения клиент-сервер и сервер-клиент в .NET существует специальная технология WCF.

Comment: Для начала, стоило бы разобраться что у вас там за хостинг и какие возможности он предоставляет...

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov , hostinger, тариф бесплатный (регистрировался еще в те далекие времена когда там был такой тариф)

Comment: @relevant интересно не название, а предоставляемые возможности

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov та собственно данный тариф ничего не предоставляет, кроме всяких банальностей (создать скрипт сайта)

Comment: @relevant что есть, в вашем понимании, банальность?

Answer (score 1):

Для двусторонней коммуникации в .NET существует фреймворк **WCF (Windows Communication Foundation)**.

Почитать подробнее можно тут -
 https://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/optimization/level5/5_4.php .

Данные на сервере чаще всего хранятся (между запросами) в базе данных, как вариант MS SQL + [EntityFramework](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/) для доступа к ним. Или [версия](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/1.1.php) для .NET Core.